# Shell script for checking a file is returning syntax error

Tags: shell

I wrote a shell script to just check whether file exists or not. Below is the snapshot:

```
#!/bin/sh
#version/300

file="test.txt"


  function file_status_check {
        if [ ! -f "$1" ]
        then
           echo  "file is already present"
        fi
           echo  "file is not present. Please create the file"
}
file_status_check $file
```

It is saying syntax error:

```
testscript.sh: 7: testscript.sh: function: not found
file is already present
file is not present. Please create the file
testscript.sh: 13: testscript.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

what am I doing wrong?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Run your script in `ksh` cell or `bash` cell and modify this first line `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/ksh` or `#!/bin/bash` Also modify your if condition like below else it will print both the statement as your `else` part is missing.

```
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]
    then
       echo  "file is already present"
    else
       echo  "file is not present. Please create the file"
    fi
```

Also your if condition is not correct here you are checking whether file is not present or not but statement is `file is already present` See my modified script below and compare with you mistakes.

```
#!/bin/bash
#version/300

file="test.txt"

function file_status_check {
    if [-f "$1" ]
    then
       echo  "file is already present"
    else
       echo  "file is not present. Please create the file"
    fi
}

file_status_check $file
```

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/sh` does not in general recognise functions defined with the `function` keyword.  This is a keyword used by `bash` and `ksh` (and possibly by some other shells).

Your script with a function could be written

```
#!/bin/sh

file_status_check () {
    if [ -f "$1" ]; then
        echo 'file present'
    else
        echo 'file not present'
    fi
}

file_status_check 'test.txt'
```

... but honestly, it would be enough with

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f 'test.txt' ]; then
    echo 'file present'
else
    echo 'file not present'
fi
```

unless you need to do this for multiple files and need to provide the same output for all of them.